# How do you get the management port for an spring boot actuator endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

I currently have a spring boot application where the actuator endpoints are exposed on a custom port. For our purposes lets say 123456. The application is fully functional I get valid responses hitting http://localhost:123456/actuator/health and http://localhost:123456/actuator/info and such.

However, when I hit the management url http://localhost:123456/actuator I get invalid endpoints. Example:

```
http://localhost/actuator/info
http://localhost/actuator/health
```

I have a Spring Boot Admin server that is trying to get my actuator endpoints and it determines the actuator endpoints by hitting the management url. However the management url is providing invalid endpoints and causing it to be unable to read them.

How do I make my actuator endpoint include the management port of the endpoints when I hit it?

Comment: What do you mean by "I get invalid endpoints"? 404? Other error codes? Stack trace in the log? Timeout? You need to tell us the full story, or it'll be very difficult to help you.

Comment: @Jorn the endpoints are missing the management port so they are invalid

Comment: Instead of http://localhost:123456/actuator/info it's http://localhost/actuator/info